# namespace conflict in C

Tags: mysql, c, list, gcc, compiler-construction

I have defined `list_t` in my project that got list module API like `list_pop()`. But now I have to use MySQL lib to communicate with DB, but the MySQL lib still got its list implements, and also defined a `list_pop()` API. In my other modules, I have to link both of them, and comes the conflict.

One of my solution is, separately include header file for different list API calling, this works well, but while some function need to call both of `MySQL::list_pop()` and `local::list_pop()`, how to notify the compiler the correct link point? Is there some GCC trick that can do these **without any changes** to `local::list_pop()`?

Comment: local::list_pop() is only valid in c++ if you're using c++ change your tags.

Comment: yes, I know, I just borrowed C++ syntax and want to make it more vivid for my question.

Comment: You could just rename your list_pop or use some macro tricks. Macro's would make your code kinda scary though so I would just rename it tbh.

Comment: @JesusRamos: Changes my list implement is the first choice, but there are tones of code depend on it, and the MySQL::list are just used in only one module, so I don't want to change my list's naming.

Comment: One other possibility: can you simply use the MySQL list type everywhere instead of your own?  Since you're building with MySQL, it might be a possibility — but probably isn't practical.

Comment: @JonathanLeffle: Once I thought about it, but only my app-level code link MySQL lib, but some of my SDK still need list, so, my app-level code included SDK list. Then, conflict.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For most practical purposes, you are going to have to rename one or the other set of functions.  It is probably easier to rename your own than those of MySQL.

The simplest approach is to simply add a prefix that has a higher probability of being unique (enough), such as your initials, or the codename of your project, or something.  Or you can rename everything to avoid collisions, being aware that MySQL might add a new function in the future.

This is exactly why namespaces were invented for C++, and why C projects usually have systematic prefixes on sets of functions.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to solve this. Refactor *your* list_pop() to, say, my_list_pop().

There is one other way to solve this,

Looking at the header of the MySQL `my_list.h` here, https://github.com/lgsonic/mysql-trigger/blob/master/mysql/my_list.h you can see that `list_pop` is just a macro, and its binded at compile time, not at runtime(hence not a real library function). Changing `list_pop` of MySQL to `list_pop_my`(just in the `#define`) can make it do what you want it to do.